Android build crashing after implementation of react-native-background-geolocation
My app got crashed after allowing location permission. Getting below error from logcat.

FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-11-thread-1
Process: com.firebase.honest, PID: 26969
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient, but class
was expected (declaration of
'com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient' appears in
/data/app/~~hu_y-IiWFIpBSx5CnSdKMQ==/com.firebase.honest-hiUPn68WsuQnMozEJwFgKQ==/base.apk!classes18.dex)
at
com.transistorsoft.xms.g.location.ActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(Unknown
Source:50)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.ActivityRecognitionService.start(Unknown
Source:78)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.TrackingService.start(Unknown
Source:49)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.adapter.BackgroundGeolocation$z0.run(Unknown
Source:145)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
[c.t.l.a.BackgroundGeolocation$w0 uncaughtException]
‼️  Uncaught Exception: Found interface
com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class
was expected (declaration of
'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears
in
/data/app/~~hu_y-IiWFIpBSx5CnSdKMQ==/com.firebase.honest-hiUPn68WsuQnMozEJwFgKQ==/base.apk!classes18.dex)
{"activityRecognitionInterval":10000,"allowIdenticalLocations":false,"authorization":{},"autoSync":true,"autoSyncThreshold":0,"backgroundPermissionRationale":{"title":"Allow
{applicationName} to access this device's location even when closed or
not in use?","message":"[CHANGEME] This app collects location data for
FEATURE X and FEATURE Y.","positiveAction":"Change to
"{backgroundPermissionOptionLabel}"","negativeAction":""},"batchSync":false,"configUrl":"","debug":true,"deferTime":0,"desiredAccuracy":-1,"desiredOdometerAccuracy":100,"disableAutoSyncOnCellular":false,"disableElasticity":false,"disableLocationAuthorizationAlert":false,"disableMotionActivityUpdates":false,"disableProviderChangeRecord":false,"disableStopDetection":false,"distanceFilter":10,"elasticityMultiplier":1,"enableHeadless":false,"enableTimestampMeta":false,"extras":{},"fastestLocationUpdateInterval":-1,"foregroundService":true,"geofenceInitialTriggerEntry":true,"geofenceModeHighAccuracy":false,"geofenceProximityRadius":1000,"geofenceTemplate":"","headers":{},"headlessJobService":"com.transistorsoft.rnbackgroundgeolocation.HeadlessTask","heartbeatInterval":-1,"httpRootProperty":"location","httpTimeout":60000,"isMoving":false,"locationAuthorizationRequest":"Always","locationTemplate":"","locationTimeout":60,"locationUpdateInterval":1000,"locationsOrderDirection":"ASC","logLevel":5,"logMaxDays":3,"maxBatchSize":-1,"maxDaysToPersist":1,"maxMonitoredGeofences":97,"maxRecordsToPersist":-1,"method":"POST","minimumActivityRecognitionConfidence":75,"motionTriggerDelay":0,"notification":{"layout":"","title":"","text":"Location
Service
activated","color":"","channelName":"TSLocationManager","channelId":"","smallIcon":"","largeIcon":"","priority":-1,"sticky":false,"strings":{},"actions":[]},"params":{},"persist":true,"persistMode":2,"schedule":[],"scheduleUseAlarmManager":false,"speedJumpFilter":300,"startOnBoot":true,"stationaryRadius":25,"stopAfterElapsedMinutes":0,"stopOnStationary":false,"stopOnTerminate":false,"stopTimeout":5,"triggerActivities":"in_vehicle,
on_bicycle, on_foot, running,
walking","url":"","useSignificantChangesOnly":false,"enabled":true,"schedulerEnabled":false,"trackingMode":1,"odometer":0,"isFirstBoot":false,"didLaunchInBackground":false,"didDeviceReboot":false}
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class
was expected (declaration of
'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears
in
/data/app/~~hu_y-IiWFIpBSx5CnSdKMQ==/com.firebase.honest-hiUPn68WsuQnMozEJwFgKQ==/base.apk!classes18.dex)
at
com.transistorsoft.xms.g.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation(Unknown
Source:50)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.location.TSLocationManager.getLastLocation(Unknown
Source:20)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.TrackingService.restart(Unknown
Source:40)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.adapter.BackgroundGeolocation.d(Unknown
Source:119)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.adapter.BackgroundGeolocation.b(Unknown
Source:14)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.adapter.BackgroundGeolocation.getInstance(Unknown
Source:10)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.scheduler.ScheduleEvent.a(Unknown
Source:32)
at
com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.scheduler.ScheduleJobService$a.run(Unknown
Source:33)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

below is my android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion:"21.3.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.transistorsoft.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        // the google-services plugin past version 4.3.15 as it requires gradle >= 7.3.0
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
    allprojects {   // <-- NOTE:  allprojects container -- If you don't see this, create it.
    repositories {
       // Required for react-native-background-geolocation
       maven { url("${project(':react-native-background-geolocation').projectDir}/libs") }
       maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
       // Required for react-native-background-fetch
       maven { url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs") }
}
    }

}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
Project background_geolocation = project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
apply from: "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/app.gradle"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.firebase.honest"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebase.honest"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 62
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            shrinkResources false
           // background_geolocation requires custom Proguard Rules
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'
//    implementation 'com.transistorsoft:tslocationmanager:3.9.4'

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

androidmainfest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:minSdkVersion="34" android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
    android:exported="true"> <!-- Add this line -->

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- If utilizing $deeplink_path please explicitly declare your hosts, or utilize a wildcard(*) -->
        <!-- REPLACE `android:scheme` with your Android URI scheme -->
        <data android:scheme="glicrx://" android:host="open" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Branch App Links - Live App -->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- REPLACE `android:host` with your `app.link` domain -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="link" />
        <!-- REPLACE `android:host` with your `-alternate` domain (required for proper functioning of App Links and Deepviews) -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="glicrx-alternate.app.link" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service
        android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.LocationService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
      <!-- Branch init -->
        <!-- REPLACE `BranchKey` with the value from your Branch Dashboard -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key" />
        <!-- REPLACE `BranchKey.test` with the value from your Branch Dashboard -->
        <!-- <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_XXX" /> -->
        <!-- Set to `true` to use `BranchKey.test` -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="default" tools:replace="android:value" />
    <!-- Branch install referrer tracking -->
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    

    </application>
</manifest>

